# Different result in ASP than in VBScript

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

If I run following code in VBScript all works as expected, if i run it in ASP (IIS 7) the I get this wrong result. Does anyone know why?

```vb
mumber = "027609366"
WScript.Echo Left(number, 2) & " " & _
             Mid(number, 3, 2) & " " & _ 
             Mid(number, 5, 2) & " " & _
             Right(number, 3)

' vbs => 03 76 09 366 (right)
' asp => 03 76 09 66  (wrong)
```

I now use the following which works:

```vb
Left(number, 2) & " " & _
Mid(number, 3, 2) & " " & _
Mid(number, 5, 2) & " " & _
Mid(number, 7)
```

But i wonder why this happens.

Comment: That can't be the exact code (since you specify `mumber` but act on `number`). Is it possible that you have an extra space at the end of `number` in the ASP case?

Comment: VBScript and classic ASP use the same language core. The results cannot be different.

Comment: General tips: *Always* use `Option Explicit` to prevent bugs from typos in variable names. Stick with `Mid()` in situations like this. Not only will the code look more consistent, it also will produce correct results when there's white-space at the end of the string - whereas `Right()` will produce different results.

Comment: Even `Mid(number,7)` would be problematic since, based on your previous symptoms it would pick up "366 " instead of "366". Use `trim` like you indicated below or use `Mid(number,7,3)` to ensure you got exactly what you were after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP code is written using VBScript, so the results can't be different, as they are technically the same thing.

Is there an extra space on the end of one of your numbers somewhere, that could be causing the number to be displayed incorrectly?

Comment: i checked the length but not on the piece that gave the problem, if i do a trim() the problem is also solved, thanks